Oracle Apex Tree like structure with Button only for child node
I want to create a tree like structure where there are BUs .. Inside BU there are departments and inside departments there are Employees. Inside employee there is Performance Q1, Performance Q2 etc.
Next to performance only there has to be a Update button. Which when clicked calls a procedure that gives rating to each employee. The rating given is shown in the next column.
Ex: If i click on Rate for John for Performance Q2,it will great as per proc logic ex: A.
It should look something like this:

I apologize for not being able to create a proper image but hope its clear.
BU when expands opens respective departments.
Department when expands shows respective employees.
Employees when expanded would show the Performance quarters next to which there should b update buttons.
Tables are as follows:
select emp_id, emp_name, dept_id, bu_id ,perf_q1, perf_q2 from employees;

select bu_id, bu_name from Business_unit;

select dept_id, dept_name from departments

Please give some idea as to how this can be achieved. The rows should be expandable and collapsible...
